# How do I prevent Ubuntu from upgrading?

Tags: installation, package-management, gpu, ubuntu-bug

I've been struggling with this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdrm/+bug/990411) the whole day. I've managed to install following the first workaround proposed, but after I install the nvidia-current drivers I end up in a small 640x480 screen and I can't select the nvidia drivers with jockey-text.

As mentioned in the bug description this doesn't seem to happen in 11.10, so I dug into my CD collection and found an old 11.04. I'm not done testing it, but so far so good.

But now I'm very afraid to update stuff. How can I prevent Ubuntu from upgrading? Or, should I look out and only **not** upgrade certain packages related to the mentioned bug?

Answer (score 0):

11.04 is out of support. You won't be getting security updates for it. So you really shouldn't be running it.

More generally, if you don't want any non-security updates, go into Software Sources, and turn off the updates repository.